# Is there a way to speed up my python recommendation script?

Tags: python, performance

To learn recommendation systems I made a pretty basic one based on some Twitter data. It works okay, the only thing is that it takes 15-20 minutes to run. I'm pretty sure I made a lot of beginner mistakes that caused this, since it should run in about half a minute.

What I do know is that this problem isn't caused by the load_data() function, since this function takes about 10 seconds without the rest of the code. Any insight on where I went wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

from operator import itemgetter
from collections import defaultdict




def load_data():

    n = 50
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f_user_sim:

        #build dictionary of all users and similarities
        sim_dict = dict()
        for line in f_user_sim:
            line = line.strip().split()
            user1, user2, sim = line[0], line[1], line[2]
            if not user1 in sim_dict:
                sim_dict[user1] = []
            sim_dict[user1].append((user2, sim))

        #for each user, sort its list of other users by similarity, resize list according to n
        for u in sim_dict:
            newlist = sorted(sim_dict[u], key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:n]
            sim_dict[u] = newlist
        return sim_dict

def VIP(user):
    with open(sys.argv[3], 'r') as f_training_matrix:
        vip_dict = list()
        for line in f_training_matrix:
           if line.split()[0] == user:
                vip_dict.append(line.split()[1])
    return vip_dict

def VIP_counter(user,simusers):
    # list of vips the user already follows
    uservips = VIP(user)
    # makes list of lists of vips that users follow
    viplist = []
    for u in simusers:
        viplist.append(VIP(u))
    # convert list of lists to counted dict
    counts = dict()
    for i in viplist:
        for j in i:
            if j not in uservips and j != user:
                counts[j] = counts.get(j,0) +1
    # sort dict
    sorteddict = sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    topten = sorteddict[:10]
    #convert list of tuples to str of keys with spaces
    return ' '.join([str(elem[0]) for elem in topten])



def main():
    simdict = load_data()

    # open input and output files
    with open(sys.argv[4], 'r') as f_input:
        with open('recommender_s2922916.dev.output', 'w+') as f_output:
           for line in f_input:
                user = line.strip()

                # make list of N similar users
                simusers = []
                for i in simdict[user][:10]:
                    simusers.append(i[0])

                # for all similar users, list every VIP they follow in list and enumerate them, output the the ten highest in spaced out string form
                counts = VIP_counter(user,simusers)
                # write the output
                f_output.write(counts)
                f_output.write('\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You can use cProfile to understand what is taking the most time and restructure your code accordingly

Comment: Apparently by far the most time was used by the split method on str objects. In my view these are necessary in my code though, don't you think?

Comment: I haven't fully gone over the code but you seem to have redundant sections. 
For eg: `if line.split()[0] == user:
                vip_dict.append(line.split()[1])`
You should keep the split line in a variable and use it twice instead of splitting twice.
Also, redundant slicing (Might not affect you much but it's a bad habit):
`for i in simdict[user][:10]:
                    simusers.append(i[0])`
use an index and avoiding wasting time and memory on slicing (creating a slice is done  in order of n)

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas dataframes to read/write/process operations of the code. It will gain more in this scenario.

eg :

```
def VIP(user):
    df = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[3], usecols=[0,1], names=['colA', 'colB'], header=None)
    return df[df.colA==user]
```

You can improve all the methods of your code without loops, comparisons,splits and new data element creation. It is not recommended to do plain operations as you done for large datasets.